# Standing upright? It's time to slice fish!

Tags: word, cryptic-clues, explanation

> Standing upright? It's time to slice fish!

Why is the answer BRISTLING?

The clue is from [The Independent Cryptic Crossword August 30, 2018](https://crossword365.com/category/independent-uk-cryptic/august-30-2018).

Comment: Where is this clue from?

Answer (score 12):

The construction is:

> **[BRISTLING](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bristling)** ("standing upright?") = **T** (*t*, symbol for time in physics) inside ("to slice") **[BRISLING](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brisling)** ("fish"). The "it's" connects definition and wordplay.
>
>  Or, in terse notation: **BRIS** (**T**) **LING**.

Comment: So the question mark in the clue doesn't hint on anything unusual? Seems like it's a normal definition.

Comment: Yes, @justhalf. A question mark can indicate something unusual or a definition by example and some styles require exclamation marks for &lit definitions, but I think here, the punctuation is only part of the surface reading.

Answer (score 4):

I was <s>snipped</s> sniped by M Oehm but, as well as Standing upright? = BRISTLING the definition, the wordplay could be:

[Bris](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bris) =  Jewish ceremony of circumcision
t = time
[ling](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ling) = fish

Comment: Haha "snipped".